# Limit in the closure of $f(A)$

Tags: general-topology, limits

**PROBLEM:** Given a function $f:A\rightarrow N$, if there exist $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=b$, then $b\in \overline{f(A)}$

Im not really sure how to proceed, I was thinking that I could split in cases, if $a\in A$ and if $a\in \overline{A}-A$. Then im pretty sure that I must use the fact that $f(A)\subset f(\overline{A})$ and if the function is continuous, $f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$ but I cant manage to join both things. I suppose its an easy question, hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Some people define $\overline{S} = \{ x : x = \lim x_n \text{ for some sequence } (x_n) \in S\}$. How do you define the closure of a set? Also keep in mind that if $a \in \overline A - A$ then $f(a)$ isn't even defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes, I could define it that way. Could you elaborate what you mean? Thanks :)

Comment: You can define $\overline{S}$ as the intersection of all closed sets containing $S$ (where you can define a closed set as either a set containing its limit points or as the complement of an open set) or you can define the closure of $S$ as taking $S$ together with its limit points (or as I do where you consider all limits, even limits of constant sequences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topological definition of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = b$:

For all open neighborhoods $V$ of $b$, there exists some open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ with $f(U - \{a\})$ as a subset of $V$.

Assume $a$ is not isolated, a necessary condition to prove the proposition.

So if $V$ is an open neighborhood of $b$, there's an
open $U$ neighborhood of $a$ with $f(U - \{a\})$ as a subset of $V$. Since $a$ is not isolated, $f(U - {a})$ is not empty.
Let $x$ be any point in $f(U - \{a\})$.
Thus $x$ is in $V \cap f(A)$.  Conclude $b$ is in the closure of $f(A)$.

No.  You have not been given that $f$ is continuous.
Use of sequences is a failure unless the spaces are first countable.